# Issue With Jellybean Menu button Android

Tags: android, menu

When I press the menu the screen button the screen fades away slowly and up pops my apparently in Jellybean. Is these issue with my code or any other stuff going on? I can't seem to find out how to change it.

Anyone know this thing?

Here is my java code with onCreateOption Menu :

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

My menu xml file "activity_main" :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Thanks,
Jay Patel

Comment: Can you specify in more detail what you mean by: " the screen fades away slowly and up pops my apparently in Jellybean "?

Comment: Actually i have implemented menu button.Sometimes when i pressed it, it doesn't work it just fades away slowly means no action has been performed after clicking it.

Comment: Nothing new in code. Code is same as we implement menu button with one of the menu xml file.

Comment: Any news on this. I've the same problem with the Nexus 7. With the same app at the Galaxy Nexus there is a menu button but not at the Nexus 7.

Comment: @AlexVogel : I didn't get any reply on this question.N still I didn't get any solution on it.

Comment: You didn't get any replies because you didn't provide enough information about your problem, no source code, no screenshots. For now it is very hard to understand your problem

Comment: @Hit : But I have no special code behind it. I have done same thing as mostly we are done by onCreteoptionmenu for menu option!!

Comment: Problem is that when I will press standard menu button to perform task its not working sometimes on jelly bean!!. N its properly working with ICS everytime!!

Comment: What is the "standard" menu button by your definition? Do you mean the hardware menu button found on older phones, or some actionbar button, or actionbar overflow button (the three dots)? Again, code would be useful. If you'll constantly refuse to post it, it creates some suspicion. Or at least post a screen shot of what happens/should happen.

Comment: @cermak.cz :Thanks for your comment!! Yes, of course in Jelly bean menu button stands as a actionbar button or action bar overflow button with three dots. Nothing new in code as we use creation method for hardware menu button.

Comment: @cermak.cz : I have updated my question with code.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Don't know, sorry. Is there a way how to replicate the issue? Could you for example create a small app that does it and post it here?

Answer (score 0):

Phones with hardware menu button wont show three dot overflow button. Instead when you press the hardware menu button the actionar items will show in popup. I dont know if that is your issue as you really provide very little info and your grammar is very unreadable.